# Checkbox id's not being submitted on form submit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using RoR 3, with form_tag, checkbox_tag, and submit_tag to submit a collection of id's to my controller.

I have a table of messages, and I want to have checkboxes that allow me to select and take actions on those items submitted. In my view:

```
<%= form_tag :name => "mailgrid",:id=>"submit",:action => "inbox_action" do  %>
...
<td class="mailbox_from"><%= check_box_tag 'msg_ids[]', message.id %></td>
...
<%= submit_tag "delete", :name => 'commit', :value=>'delete' %>
<% end %>
```

This produces HTML that looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/messages/inbox_action/submit?name=mailgrid" method="post">
...
<input id="msg_ids_" name="msg_ids[]" style="position:relative;top:-2px;right:10px;" type="checkbox" value="88" />
...
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="delete" /> </div>
```

Then, in my controller:

```
  if params[:msg_ids]
      #dostuff
  end
```

However, whether those checkboxes are selected never gets passed to my controller. In my logs those parameters are missing entirely, even though this controller method does get called. Here's the log:

> Started POST "/messages/inbox_action/submit?name=mailgrid" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-05 19:43:02 -0800
>
> Processing by MessagesController#inbox_action as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asdf", "commit"=>"delete", "name"=>"mailgrid", "id"=>"submit"}

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you ending your form with `<% end %>`?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html  
I think you should use "form_for" for your model CRUD

Comment: This isn't specifically tied to model actions, so I wanted to use form_tag as it's more generic.

Yes, I'm ending the form with `<% end %>`. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try with

```
<%= check_box_tag......., params[:your_param], ..... %>
```

i am newbie in ruby, but seems thats the problem, i can be wrong, but

Comment: No, no matter what I put in that check_box_tag, nothing gets passed to the controller.